# Visual studio 2017 installation issue on windows 8/8.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

We are not getting core 2.0 template after installation Vs2017 community edition.
[image]

Comment: In "programs and features" is the box for .net  2.0 and 3 checked? If not,do so and install this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Environment Variable the Path was setup wrong.

1. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet' removed
2. 'C:\Program Files\dotnet' set